Estne in lingua Latina verbum quod significat incipere in scholam ire, ut Anglicum verbum "enroll" vel Croaticum verbum "upisati"?
Estne in lingua Latina verbum quod significat incipere in scholam ire, ut Anglicum verbum "en-roll" (in-volvere) vel Croaticum verbum "u-pisati" (in-scribere)?

Maybe mātriculō? This might be a medieval Latin word. I just googled, though, and at a first glance, there seems to be no attestation of it.

@BenKovitz Are you sure "matriculo" doesn't mean "to graduate"?

I'm not 100% sure, but I would expect not, because the noun mātrīcula means "list, register", and the English verb "matriculate" means to enroll in a university, and the etymology suggests a Latin verb mātrīculō meaning the same.

Traupman translates asciscere aliquem inter patricios as "to enroll someone in the patrician order".
Running with this, I would translate "to enroll in a university as ascisci inter discipulos universitatis.
Traupman also recommends adscribi as an alternative to ascisci. That might suit a school better, if ascisci is seen as too ceremonial.
